# Read and write at the same time Matlab

Tags: java, matlab, file

I have a sensor that write the data he collect to a txt file (continuously, one per second) the only data i care about is the last data the sensor collect,
i want to analyze the data with Matlab (or Java), how can it be done?
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to be able to watch the file for updates, and then take some action when a change is detected.  I believe previously this had to be done with polling mechanisms, but in Java 7 you can use a `WatchService`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    Path dir = Paths.get("src/main/resources/");
    try {
        WatchService watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
        WatchKey key = dir.register(watcher, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY);

        while (true){
            watcher.take();
            List<WatchEvent<?>> events = key.pollEvents();
            // Handle update

            key.reset();
        }
    } catch (IOException x) {
        System.err.println(x);
    }
}
```

I'd suggest you think carefully about thread safety in how you handle the update - I'd suggest copying the file to a safe "staging" location before reading it, to avoid read/write collisions with the updating process.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a minor modification of the [http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fgetl.html](http://read%20lines%20from%20file%20example)

```
fid = fopen('sensor.txt');
tline = fgetl(fid);
while 1
    if ischar(tline)
        disp(tline)   
    else
        pause(1)
    end
    tline = fgetl(fid);
end
```

That's not a finished solution, think about when to close the file. There is a `flose(fid)` missing and the code currently runs in a infinite loop. Use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to exit it.